# How to destandardize PCA scores in R

Tags: r, pca, standardization

I ran PCA in R using the principal() function in the "psych" package.

Suppose my dataset is called "data" (118 rows and 8 columns).
The 8 variables are answers from a questionnaire, with a scale that ranges from 1 to 7.

From the PCA, 2 principal components are extracted. Next, I ran again the principal function in order to apply the varimax orthogonal rotation.

```
pc_rotated <- principal(data, nfactors=2, rotate="varimax", scores=TRUE)
```

The scores could be extracted by:

```
scores <- pc_rotated$scores
```

My question is: how do I destandardize the scores I get?

I need the two components in the original scale (1 to 7).

Edit: Further question, how this function ( principal() ) calculates the loadings? I calculate the eigenvectors of the correlation matrix but these are different from the loadings proposed by the function.

Comment: Please be specific. Your original variables are discrete, from 1 to 7 points. Components are continuous. How do you imagine the final result you are after? Eigenvectors are unit-standardizrd loadings. Loadings (before rotation) are eigenvectors scaled up to the respective eigenvalues.

Comment: I didn't get the first part of your answer. I mean if I run the PCA on discrete values I will have discrete results of the PCA. the reason I'm doing this is to reduce dimensionality. But it was just an example, say that I have a database with continuous variables, how do you destandardize the final scores? Is it possible?

Comment: What is "destandardize"? Give it specific mean and variance? What mean and variance then? Note that variance of a component is its loadings sum of squares.

Comment: That is exactly my question. The "principal" function gives standardized scores as default. I wonder if it is possible from that result obtain a result with the variables that are non standardized. (with that package you enter data that is not standard and you get standard results as default)

Comment: I give you an example, say my DB <- matrix(c(1,3,2,3,6,4,7,8,9,3,6,9), 4, 3, byrow=T) and I ran the PCA: pca <- principal(DB, nfactors=3, scores=T). I get standardized scores (pca$scores). Is there a way to obtain scores that are not standard? And how this package calculates the scores?

Comment: Non-standardized scores are equal to the standardized scores times square roots of respective eigenvalues (given by `principal()$values`). But it sounds like you expect non-standardized scores to be on the same discrete 1-7 scale as the original variables. This will not be the case! As @ttnphns said, PC scores are continuous (not discrete!) and some of them will have much larger variance than the original variables, if of course those show any correlation at all.